# what's affecting my zinnias?

Tags: diagnosis, flowers

These are a liliput variety of zinnias that I started from seed during may.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Most affected plant

[image: Most affected plant]

They were doing fine when they were on the small germination pots but after repotting them directly to the ground they started developing necrosis that starts from the tip and quickly extends throughout the entire leaf.

It progresses fast, with an entire set of leaves destroyed every day or two.

Oddly enough the cotyledons are mostly unaffected or are the lasts to be damaged.

These ones were germinated directly in the soil when I transplanted the others and some are beginning to show the same signs of disease

[image]

The soil is a combination of approximately 90% potting mix and 10% existing clay soil where nothing has been planted for a while.

They get intense direct sunlight until 1-2 pm. Thinking that it could be sunburn I started to cover them during the midday hours but as the leaf damage kept progressing and it starts from the tips I think I can discard that.

Since there's signs of insect damage perhaps it's some disease spread by them? Can they be saved or should I remove them? Thanks

Comment: Sun damage on Mexican flowers? No. Maybe too wet and encouraging fungus.